# How do I tell an EditForm to not validate?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I use the same EditForm to Create, Read, & Update an object. For Create & Update I want validation. But for Read, if an object fails validation (due to being read in from a batch import), I don't want validation.

In fact, validation is not only a bad UX, it's an impossible situation because all the fields are in read-only mode and therefore the bad value can't be corrected.

How can I turn off validation?

Here's the razor page. Note the `ReadOnly="ModeState == Mode.Read)"` in places

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext"
          OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync"
          OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync"
          Context="EditFormContext">
    <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidation @ref="_customValidation" />
    <DxFormLayout>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Region:" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxComboBox @bind-Value="@Model.Region"
                        ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
                        Data="@AllRegions"
                        TextFieldName="Name"
                        AllowUserInput="false"
                        ListRenderMode="ListRenderMode.Entire"
                        FilteringMode="@(ModeState == Mode.Read ? DataGridFilteringMode.None : DataGridFilteringMode.Contains)"
                        ShowValidationIcon="true" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Name:" Field="@nameof(Model.Name)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Model.Name"
                       ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
                       ShowValidationIcon="true" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="Unique Id:" Field="@nameof(Model.UniqueId)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@Model.UniqueId"
                       ReadOnly="@(ModeState != Mode.Create)"
                       ShowValidationIcon="true" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>

        <AddressForm @ref="_addressElement"
                     Context="@EditContext"
                     ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
                     OnValidated="OnAddressValidated"
                     ValueChanged="@OnAddressChanged" />

        @* Read & Update modes only - the booleans *@
        <DxFormLayoutItem Visible="@(ModeState != Mode.Create)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Model.Enabled"
                        ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)">Enabled</DxCheckBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Visible="@(ModeState != Mode.Create)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Model.Closed"
                        ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)">Closed</DxCheckBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem Visible="@(ModeState != Mode.Create)" ColSpanMd="4">
            <DxCheckBox @bind-Checked="@Model.Deleted"
                        ReadOnly="true">Deleted</DxCheckBox>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="12">
            <ValidationSummary />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="12">
            <DxButton Enabled="@SubmitEnabled"
                      Text="@SubmitButtonText"
                      SubmitFormOnClick="true"
                      RenderStyle="@ButtonRenderStyle.Secondary" />
        </DxFormLayoutItem>

    </DxFormLayout>
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Please enter the code

Comment: Where are you triggering validation in your read only environment?  There shouldn't be any buttons to click to "submit" the form?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis When I click [Close]. I have a button at the bottom that says either [Create], [Update], or [Close} based on the mode.

Comment: Is your close button a submit button? Set the type to button so that it doesn’t trigger validation.

Comment: Can you please show your button code in the question?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - added the razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  You simply don't submit the form, and use some logic to change the submit button configuration..

Here's a quick demo of how to change the button modes:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model=_model OnValidSubmit="this.ValidSubmit" >
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Value</label>
        <InputText disabled="@_readOnly" class="form-control" @bind-Value=_model.Value />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _model.Value" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-end mb-3 col-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-2" @onclick=this.SwitchMode>Switch Mode</button>
        @if (_readOnly)
        {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=this.Exit>Exit</button>
        }
        else
        {
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        }
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div class="m-2">
</div>
@code {
    public bool _readOnly = true;
    public Model _model = new();

    public void ValidSubmit()
    {
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
    }

    public void SwitchMode()
        => _readOnly = !_readOnly;

    public class Model
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid - that's an incredibly obvious answer now that you posted it - thanks